# Create a Map in Plotly Using Two Files With plot_mapbox

Tags: r, plotly, mapbox, geojson

Thanks for reading my post. I am trying to create one map in Plotly using R by layering data from 2 data sources and the function plot_mapbox. The map will show locations of stores in zoned business districts.

test is a geoJSON file of zoning districts
test2 is a csv file of business locations using longitude and latitude coordinates

I've tried layering the data and combining two geoJSON files. The first file is a geoJSON file (business zones)and the second file is a .csv (store locations) with longitude and latitude. I converted the csv file to a geoJSON file and then tried to merge them. I would really need to append them since they don't have a common key.

```
library(plotly)
library(geojsonR)
library(sf)
test<-st_read("D:/SPB/Zoning_Detailed.geojson", quiet=FALSE, , geometry_column="SHAPE_Area")
test2<-read.csv("D:/SPB/Pet_Bus.csv")
```

One layering exampe

```
plot_mapbox(data=test, color=~ZONING) %>%
  add_markers(data=test2, x=~Longitude, y=~Latitude)
  layout(mapbox=list(style = "streets"))
```

One merge example (only the first file is added in merge) 
files Zoning_Detailed.geojson and Pet_Bus.geojson are in the Merge folder. I
converted Pet_Bus.csv to a geojson file.
This should really be append since test and test2 are independent of each other, but in same city.

```
merge_files("D:/SPB/Merge/", "D:/SPB/Merge/test7.geojson")
```